# Conversion of Multiple Strings To ASCII

Tags: python

This seems fairly trivial but I can't seem to work it out

I have a text file with the contents:

> B>F

I am reading this with the code below, stripping the '>' and trying to convert the strings into their corresponding ASCII value, minus 65 to give me a value that will correspond to another list index

```
def readRoute():
    routeFile = open('route.txt', 'r')
    for line in routeFile.readlines():
        route = line.strip('\n' '\r')
        route = line.split('>')
        #startNode, endNode = route
        startNode = ord(route[0])-65
        endNode = ord(route[1])-65

    # Debug  (this comment was for my use to explain below the print values)
    print 'Route Entered:'
    print line
    print startNode, ',', endNode, '\n'
    return[startNode, endNode]
```

However I am having slight trouble doing the conversion nicely, because the text file only contains one line at the moment but ideally I need it to be able to support more than one line and run an amount of code for each line.

For example it could contain:

```
B>F
A>D 
C>F 
E>D
```

So I would want to run the same code outside this function 4 times with the different inputs

Anyone able to give me a hand

### Edit:

Not sure I made my issue that clear, sorry

What I need it do it parse the text file (possibly containing one line or multiple lines like above. I am able to do it for one line with the lines

```
startNode = ord(route[0])-65
endNode = ord(route[1])-65
```

But I get errors when trying to do more than one line because the `ord()` is expecting different inputs
If I have (below) in the route.txt

```
B>F
A>D
```

This is the error it gives me:

```
line 43, in readRoute  endNode = ord(route[1])-65
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

My code above should read the route.txt file and see that B>F is the first route, strip the '>' - convert the B & F to ASCII, so 66 & 70 respectively then minus 65 from both to give 1 & 5 (in this example)
The 1 & 5 are corresponding indexes for another "array" (list of lists) to do computations and other things on
Once the other code has completed it can then go to the next line in route.txt which could be A>D and perform the above again

Comment: Are you asking how to put code into the indented block inside the `for` loop?  When you indented the "# Debug" what did you observe?

Comment: You'll probably need to be more explicit about the 'other computations' to get a useful answer. If possible I'd try to separate the parsing from the computations to keep the logic as clean as possible.

Comment: @Michael This function is separate from the computations, it will parse the file convert and pass its returned values to other functions
Only when THEY are complete it will need to read the next line (if it exists)

Comment: I added a demonstrative function for you to call your custom logic from. The reason I suggested you need to be more explicit is because I have no idea what you plan to do in that logic section and whether that logic will affect the next line of values read from the file.

Comment: Given your desire to return values to other functions BEFORE making additional readlines, a generator is the perfect device. As shown in my solution, one line is read at a time, you are able to return the two node-values and pass them to other functions as necessary, before continuing the file-read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you. I turned the fileread into a generator so you can do as you please with the parsed results in the for-i loop.

```
def readRoute(file_name): 
    with open(file_name, 'r') as r:
        for line in r:
            yield (ord(line[0])-65, ord(line[2])-65)

filename = 'route.txt'

for startnode, endnode in readRoute(filename):
    print startnode, endnode
```

Comment: Also, any additional code you'd want to run on the pre-parsed pair can be easily inserted in the 'for line in r' construct.

Comment: How can I use the yield command to mimic this
`startNode = ord(route[0])-65`
`endNode = ord(route[2])-65`
So I am able to set the variables

Comment: You can replace the for-i with: 'for startnode, endnode in readRoute(filename)' to get yourself more conveniently named vars to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change readRoute, change the contents of the file before each call.  Better yet, make readRoute take the filename as a parameter (default it to 'route.txt' to preserve the current behavior) so you can have it process other files.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? It takes the routes defined in your file and turns them into path objects with `start` and `end` member variables. As an added bonus `PathManager.readFile()` allows you to load multiple route files without overwriting the existing paths.

```
import re

class Path:
  def __init__(self, start, end):
     self.start = ord(start) - 65  # Scale the values as desired
     self.end = ord(end) - 65  # Scale the values as desired

class PathManager:
  def __init__(self):
    self.expr = re.compile("^([A-Za-z])[>]([A-Za-z])$") # looks for string "C>C" 
                                                        # where C is a char
    self.paths = []

  def do_logic_routine(self, start, end):
    # Do custom logic here that will execute before the next line is read
    # Return True for 'continue reading' or False to stop parsing file
    return True

  def readFile(self, path):
    file = open(path,"r")
    for line in file:
      item = self.expr.match(line.strip()) # strip whitespaces before parsing
      if item:
        '''
        item.group(0) is *not* used here; it matches the whole expression
        item.group(1) matches the first parenthesis in the regular expression
        item.group(2) matches the second
        '''
        self.paths.append(Path(item.group(1), item.group(2)))
        if not do_logic_routine(self.paths[-1].start, self.paths[-1].end):
          break

# Running the example
MyManager = PathManager()
MyManager.readFile('route.txt')
for path in MyManager.paths:
  print "Start: %s End: %s" % (path.start, path.end)
```

Output is:

```
Start: 1 End: 5
Start: 0 End: 3
Start: 2 End: 5
Start: 4 End: 3
```